# put an item on the tabs above in IONIC?

Tags: html, css, position, ionic-framework

I want to put an element, in this case a `<div>`. I want this on the tabs as shown in the picture.
[image]
 I have tried many things, but does not work me. This view is a template, in another file are the tabs.

```
<ion-view title='<ion-nav-buttons class="btn-retroceder" side="left"><a class="button button-icon" href="#/MenuPrincipal"><i class="ion-chevron-left"></i></a></ion-nav-buttons>'>
  <ion-content ng-controller="TomaDecisionesController">
            <div class="bar bar-header bar-tomaDecisiones">
                     <h1 class="title tituloBarToma"> title</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="padding contenido-toma-decisiones">
            <label class="item " href="#">
                        <select  ng-model="eps1"  class="item item-input" style='width: 100%;'>
                            <option style="display:none" value="">x</option>

                        </select>
            </label>
            <label class="item " href="#">
                        <select  ng-model="eps2"  class="item item-input" style='width: 100%;'>
                            <option style="display:none" value="">x</option>

                        </select>
            </label>  
           </div>
//*******************
//this is the div 
           <div>
                <label class="item " href="#" >
                            <select  ng-model="criterio"  class="item item-input" style='width: 100%;'>
                                <option style="display:none" value="">CRITERIO</option>
                                <option  value="">CRITERIO2</option>
                                <option value="">CRITERIO3</option>
                            </select>
                </label>  
            </div>

  <ion-content>
```

I want this div always this fixed, in the same position. (likewise as do the tabs)

Answer (score 0):

has you said 'u have tried lot'..just try this also.may be helpful.
add this with tabs as shown.

`style="bottom:54px;"` is bcoz, tabs is overriding over it.u can find more good way to do this.

```
<div class="tabs " style="bottom:54px;display: block">
  <label class="item block " href="#" >
    <select  ng-model="criterio"  class="item item-input block" style='width: 100%;'>
      <option style="display:none" value="">CRITERIO</option>
      <option  value="">CRITERIO2</option>
      <option value="">CRITERIO3</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>

<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

  <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.home">
    <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-people"">
    <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: thanks! but if I do this, it would be in all tabs. I just want this in this template ..